# Insert div after click and pass data to Contact Form 7

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have contact form on my site. I have a row with class "cargo" which includes contact form 7 fields.

```
        <div class="cargo">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [text dlugosc class:default-font placeholder "Długość"]
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [text szerokosc class:default-font placeholder "Szerokość"]
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [text wysokosc class:default-font placeholder "Wysokość"]
            </div>     
        </div>
```

below I have button which should add another "cargo" row

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default green-second-gradient-btn default-button-font add-cargo" value="Dodaj kolejny ładunek +">
```

My question is: how can I add another row "cargo" and pass this data to CF7?
If I have 1 cargo row my mail should look like this:

`Cargo 1: XX, YY, ZZ`

If I have 2 cargo rows my mail should look like this:

`Cargo 1: XX, YY, ZZ`

`Cargo 2: AA, BB, CC`

etc. How Can I do this? Also, I want to add "delete row" button next to every cargo row but not next to first.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please share pieces of code of what you have tried.

Comment: For now I have something like this but it's adding 1, 2, 4 etc. rows. I don't know how to manipulate CF7 inputs name etc.

    $('.add-cargo').click(function(){
       $('.cargo').clone().insertAfter(".cargo");
    });

Comment: use append instead of insertAfter

Comment: now I have this $('.cargo:first').clone().insertAfter(".cargo:last"); and it works. Know I need to add my cloned inputs value to my contact form email but I don't know how.